# How to authenticate mongodb connection in mongoose node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have created admin user using

```
use admin
db.createUser(
   {
       user: "username",
       pwd: "password",
       roles: [ ]
   }
)
```

how to map these credentials  to `mongoose.connect` in [Standard Connection String Format on mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/).

or any other way so that I can authenticate connection. If `username` and `password` are invalid/not provided connection should be failed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the couple login/password directly in the connection url, for instance

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@host:port');
```

In this case if credentaisl aren't valid, you'll get an erreor on connection.

Hope that it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Common = {

// Node Module dependencies 
express : require('express'),

bodyParser : require('body-parser'),

autoIncrement : require('mongoose-auto-increment'),

mongoose : require('mongoose'),

Schema:require('mongoose').Schema,

conn:require('mongoose').createConnection('mongodb://localhost/XYZ'),

// check if the user is authenticated and can access resources 
ensureAuthenticated : function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    }
    res.redirect('/');
}

};
```

I have created a refering class called common.js.
If you refer this connection class from a different class like common.ensureAuthenticated(username,password).It will work